# what are the prerequisite for learning spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I started my mvc experience with cakephp and I really enjoy it. So i would like to expand my knowledge with spring mvc. I have been searching online and all i got is confusion. So if possible I would like to know the prerequisite that you must know before using spring mvc.

Comment: You don't learn such a large framework by "searching online". You read the documentation, and/or a good book about it, and you practice.

Comment: i think i wasn't clear sorry, i want to know the list of things to know before digging into spring mvc. I am not talking about how to do it, i just want the names and topics like: fundamentals of java, fundamentals of mvc .... like that, then i will look into each one of them and learn it through books

Comment: Basic understaning of 1.Core Java 2.Servlets 3.MVC design Pattern 4.Spring Core ***in that order***. I recommend ***Mini MVC Tutorial*** chapter from Head First Servlets & JSP book by kathy sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Spring Boot. There are many tutorials (also from Spring itself) and a good manual. Boot configures most of Spring MVC automatically for you, so that you can start experimenting with a real use case pretty quickly, with minimal config and boilerplate.

For simple websites you can look for Spring Boot + Thymeleaf tutorials, or even Spring + Angular, Vue or React if you like.